# BS4 - Web Scraping - Searching div. class =

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape '95% liked this Movie' from the image below, but getting no result when I specify the tag via the class - view code below. Any idea on how I can attain this?

```
import bs4, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS879US879&sxsrf=ALeKk00cw9xBpC8OWgCnKhMSIGOi4xb3sw%3A1590372307467&ei=0yfLXrSQHNHa9AOzh6jIAg&q=titanic+google+play&oq=Titanic+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIIxAnMgoIABCDARAUEIcCMgcIABCDARBDMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBwgAEIMBEEMyBAgAEEMyBwgAEIMBEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEM6BAgAEEc6AggAOgUIABCDAVCcLFjMOmCEQ2gBcAN4AIABbIgBigaSAQM4LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab')

res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
news = [p.text.strip() for p in soup.select('h1 ~ p') if p.find('font')]

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
content = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
content.find_all(class="srBp4.Vrkhme")`
```

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mjeb.png)

Comment: Google usually uses JavaScript to display elements but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. Turn off JavaScript in browser and reload your page with Google and you will see what `BeautifulSoup` can see. As I remeber Google sends different `HTML` when client can't run JavaScript.

Comment: BTW: you can also save HTML which you get with BS and display in browser to see if you didn't get warning for bots or recaptcha which blocks bots. Google doesn't like scripts/bots and it has big money to create complex system for blocking bots. It has also different APIs to serve some data instead of getting them from HTML

Comment: @furas thank you - ya i cannot find the API that gets this data.

Comment: @furas it would be so great to get all this data

Comment: turn off JavaScript in web browser and reload page to see what `BeautifulSoup` can get from Google - and then get values for `select()`, `find()`. BTW: when I use your URL then I don't get information about movie - Google  may sends different results for different users. You may have to use Private Mode in web browser when you test Google results because your script is like Private Mode. Google may also send different HTML for different devices (phone, tablet, desktop) and it depends on header `User-Agent` which you don't use in `requests`. Maybe save `res.text` in file and open it in browser

Comment: @furas thank you. When I turned off JavaScript , the “95% Liked ..” text no longer shows up. So you said your in the same boat that you cannot scrape this data ?

Comment: use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses JavaScript to display results - to get `95% ...` I had to use `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. And I had to use query `titanic movie` instead of `titanic google play`

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=titanic+movie'

#driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

item = driver.find_element_by_class_name('srBp4.Vrkhme')
print(item.text.strip())
```

---

**EDIT:** I get it also with `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` but I had to use full header `User-Agent`. It doesn't work with short `Mozilla/5.0`

And it needs class `"srBp4 Vrkhme"` without dot. And it has to be `class_=` with `_`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=titanic+movie', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
item = soup.find('div', class_="srBp4 Vrkhme")
print(item.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```